# Protractor - empty local storage

Tags: local-storage, protractor

I'm using Protractor (with Jasmine) to test my AngulaJs application.

As result of some of my action I get some data saved in the localStorage. Now I need to test other case, so I need to empty my storage (or better delete only some items) but If I try to run:

```
browser.executeScript('localStorage.removeItem("config");');
```

I get the following error:

```
UnknownError: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
  (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.2 x86_64)
```

Any idea on how to solve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got this error when I tried running protractor test suite without serving the application. I re-ran the tests after serving the application and it was fine after that. noting it here for future users who might face this error

Comment: @MalliKharjunaRao I'm glad I'm not the only dummy. Exact same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 41):

Another potential solution is to put any state clearing in an afterEach, which will run after any test is run: (see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/188)

```
afterEach(function() {
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
});
```

Comment: `Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.`

Comment: Ensure that you hit a page in the browser before finishing your test, otherwise you run into this on Chrome browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259235/remove-an-item-from-localstorage-in-a-protractor-test for more information.

Comment: thanks, that explains why it didn't work when using it in beforeEach with phantomJS

Comment: In my case, I have login as two user to perform the operation. I have used the above code after the first user log out and during the second user login I face session issue. How can we handle this?

Answer (score 19):

It's because you haven't navigated to a valid url yet. Do a `browser.get('/foo')` before trying to interact with page objects like `localStorage`.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by checking the window.location before attempting to clear/modify sessionStorage or localStorage.

If a page has not been loaded then `window.location.hostname` will equal the empty string `''`. So if you get the emptystring, then don't attempt to interact with `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

Here's some (ES6) code I used in my protractor suite to prevent this error. Note it's a cucumber-js After function, but it is still executed from protractor using chrome, and it demonstrates what you need to do to avoid this error:

```
this.After(function(scenario) {

  function getWindowLocation() {
    return window.location;
  }

  function clearStorage() {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.clear();
  }

  return browser.executeScript(getWindowLocation).then(function(location) {
    // NB If no page is loaded in the scneario then calling clearStorage will cause exception
    // so guard against this by checking hostname (If no page loaded then hostname == '')
    if (location.hostname.length > 0) {
      return browser.executeScript(clearStorage);
    }
    else {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a cool way to do that, but if I run my statement

```
 browser.executeScript("localStorage.removeItem('config');")
```

within a it('description') statement it works. Example:

```
it('should compile and save base config for billing',function(){
    browser.executeScript("localStorage.removeItem('config');")

    //my test
});
```

This remove the item named config, and so my test works, but while searching and talking about this issue the main response I got is:

"localStorage is not you product, so you don't need (read: you must not) test it. The right way is to mock it and inject it contents when they are needed"

I'm still looking into this to understrand how, meanwhile I think that a not philosophically perfect test is still better than nothing so..

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is a functional test on a real browser so you have to interact with the real localStorage. The "localStorage is not your product" answer only applies to unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

If there's still a problem with the localStorage when executing a "removeItem()", you can use a try-catch, like:

```
browser.executeScript("try {localStorage.removeItem('access_token');} catch(exception) {}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full control of your storage, use this class

```
class Storage {
    constructor(storage) {
        // 'localStorage' or 'sessionStorage'
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    /**
     * get local/session storage as object
     * @returns {Promise<Object>}
     */
    async get() {
        log(`${this.storage}.get()`);
        let keys = await browser.executeScript(`return Object.keys(window.${this.storage});`),
            storage = {};

        for (let key of keys) {
            storage[key] = await browser.executeScript(`return window.${this.storage}.getItem('${key}');`);
        }

        return storage;
    }

    /**
     * Clear local/session storage
     * @returns null
     */
    async clear() {
        log(`${this.storage}.clear()`);
        return browser.executeScript(`return window.${this.storage}.clear();`);
    }

    /**
     * Set a value of local/session storage
     * @param key
     * @param value
     * @returns
     */
    async setValue(key, value) {
        log(`${this.storage}.setValue(${key}, ${value})`);
        return browser.executeScript(`return window.${this.storage}.setItem('${key}', '${value}');`);
    }

    /**
     * Get value of a key of local/session storage
     * @param key
     * @returns
     */
    async getValue(key) {
        log(`${this.storage}.getValue(${key})`);
        return browser.executeScript(`return window.${this.storage}.getItem('${key}');`);
    }

    async removeItem(key) {
        log(`${this.storage}.removeItem(${key})`);
        return browser.executeScript(`return window.${this.storage}.removeItem('${key}');`);
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
let sessionStorage = new Storage('sessionStorage'),
    localStorage = new Storage('localStorage');

// get storage as JSON
console.log(await sessionStorage.get())
// clear storage
await localStorage.clear();
// set key
await localStorage.setValue('key', 'value');
// and many more
```