# Should Protractor See Chrome's Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, protractor

I run a protractor test (pretty irrelevant example):

```
describe('Test something.', function(){
    it('Should do something', function(){
        browser.get('http://localhost:22222/something');
    });
})
```

This takes me to our login page instead of the 'something' page (checks local storage for token, doesn't find it). I am already logged in and have the info in LS on Chrome. I don't understand why the test doesn't see it - I thought the Chrome Driver ran on actual Chrome, so it should use the same local storage as, well, Chrome...because it's, you know...Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it IS the same Chrome that I run 'by hand,' it DOES share local
>   storage?

Nope, when you run `protractor` the initially started Chrome is a "brand-new" clean Chrome with an empty local storage, empty cookies etc.

But, you can always verify and manage the local storage using the following "helper" object:

```
"use strict";

var LocalStorage = function () {
    this.getValue = function (key) {
        return browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('" + key + "');");
    };

    this.get = function () {
        browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage;");
    };

    this.clear = function () {
        browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.clear();");
    };
};

module.exports = new LocalStorage();
```

Also see:

- [Protractor - empty local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205856/protractor-empty-local-storage)

Comment: Thank you for that, but my theoretical question stands - it IS the same Chrome that I run 'by hand,' it DOES share local storage? I.e. if I set local storage in Chrome through a protractor script, close the browser, and then open Chrome from the start menu or desktop, it should have LS set?  And vice versa.

Comment: @VSO I've improved the answer a little bit. Note that if you want to skip the  "auth" part, put the token into the local storage in, for instance, `onPrepare()` or `beforeEach()`. The browser would then restart from spec to spec during the test run, but the token value would exist in the local storage.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the edit - that's what I needed. Thank you.