# Protractor: clear browsing data completely

Tags: selenium, cookies, protractor

I'm looking for a way to completely delete all cookies, session/state cookies, storage, etc. using Protractor. Basically, I want to accomplish the same thing in Protractor as a user would by going to Settings -> Clear browsing data.

`browser.manage().deleteAllCookies()` does not delete httpOnly cookies. And since JavaScript can't touch httpOnly cookies, I can't use JavaScript.

I know I could restart the browser in Protractor, but prefer not to go this route.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this if it helps : https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/172  upshot is try : browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

Comment: I've used both `browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` and `browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()`. It does not delete session cookies.

Comment: I've tried `browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` and executing javascript snippets such as `window.localStorage.clear()`. There is some aspect of state being preserved across different tests, which is problematic for me as well. It would be useful to have the freedom to terminate the browser between tests, as this is something easily doable when working with ordinary Selenium Webdriver tests. Edit: `browser.restart()` appears to be an alternative worth exploring here.

Answer (score 10):

This answer by Anthony Panozzo was the best way for me to clear session and local storage (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678498/5072980)

```
afterEach(function() {
  browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
  browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
});
```

Comment: I believe this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: No, it is not the correct way of deleting cookies. Deleting session or local storage does not delete cookies.