# Protractor takes blank screenshot when using browser.restart() function to start another TC in new Browser Window

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have two specs to be executed in new browser everytime, so my afterEach function has browser.restart() to restart browser after every spec. But this causes protractor to take blank screenshot. When I remove the browser.restart(), my another spec runs in the same browser window which causes the spec to fail. Any lead will be helpful.

Below is my conf.js

```
onPrepare: function()
{
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: 'target/screenshots',
            takeScreenshots: true,
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: false
        })
    );
},
```

Below is my Spec.js

```
afterEach(function(){
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
browser.restart();
});
```

Actual Code

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("siteId"))),5000);
element(by.id("files")).click();
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
element(by.id("toggleFilter")).element(by.xpath('div/div/form/div[4]/div/button[2]')).click();
element(by.id("toggleFilter")).element(by.xpath('div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/span')).getText().then(function(msg){
    expect(msg).toBe(pre.errorMsg);
})
```

Comment: Please put your code out, it can help us to know more about your question

Comment: Could this an async issue where the screenshot is scheduled but the browser restarts before the screenshot has actually completed? Try putting in a 5 second delay before the restart and see if it captures successfully. If it does you can proceed from there

Comment: Tried adding 3 seconds delay but same behavior, blank screenshot.

Comment: afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
      browser.sleep(3000);
      browser.restart();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that Jasmine is creating the failure screenshots in it's `specDone` hook but this is not called until after Protractor's `afterEach` hook has already completed, thereby restarting the browser before the screenshot taking action is triggered. You should be to test this by moving your browser.restart to the `beforeEach` hook and see if it now behaves as expected.

However long term it is not ideal as for the first test you are restarting the browser before any actions take place. [See this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909593/protractor-takes-blank-screenshots-when-restartbrowserbetweentests-true-is-se?rq=1) as it lists another approach which could help you

**Hook execution order**

```
--- beforeLaunch           
    --- onPrepare          
      --- jasmineStarted   (set in jasmine reporter)
        --- beforeAll
         --- suiteStarted  (set in jasmine reporter)
          --- specStarted  (set in jasmine reporter)
           --- beforeEach  
           +++ afterEach   
          +++ specDone     (set in jasmine reporter)
         +++ suiteDone     (set in jasmine reporter)
        +++ afterAll
      +++ jasmineDone      (set in jasmine reporter)
    +++ onComplete         
+++ afterLaunch
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use browser.restart()
For new browser window you can use following code:

```
 browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    const newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
    browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
      return browser.getCurrentUrl()
      });
        });
```