# Set an item from localStorage in a protractor test

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

```
describe('The feature', function() {     
    beforeEach(function () {
       browser.executeScript('localStorage.setItem("key","value");');
    });

   it('should do this', function() {

   });
});
```

but i get this error when the test is run against selenium with chromedriver 2.10 and chrome 37

```
Executing: [execute script: window.localStorage.setItem("key","value");, []])
15:31:29.747 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage'
property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
(Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.11.0-26-generic x86_64) (WARNING:  
The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Any idea where the problem cam from ?

Comment: Does `window.localStorage` work for you?

Comment: No. I have tried that already.

Answer (score 11):

According to one of the answers at [Remove an item from localStorage in a protractor test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259235/remove-an-item-from-localstorage-in-a-protractor-test?lq=1), this happens when you try to access localStorage without hitting the browser (say, `browser.get`) first when you are using the Chrome driver. The solution seems to be to hit the browser first (maybe your root page) to get a page loaded in Chrome so that you can manipulate the localStorage. That at least is what I have been doing for our project. Hope this helps!