# "Uncaught (in promise) SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.", in Flutter

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I need to call a js function in a flutter app to load a payment dashboard page. So I use the WebViewPlus flutter package to do that. I write the HTML code inside the dart page and call with the help of WebViewPlus. it loads correctly. but when I call the js function in a button press it tries to load but gives an error. i.e "Uncaught (in promise) SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.",
How can I clear the storage issue in the WebViewPlus package? my code is here

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_plus/webview_flutter_plus.dart';

class WebViewStorage extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebViewStorage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewPlus(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          controller.loadString('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://bla.blabla.io/bla.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="savingContainer"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 const credentials = {
      token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     }
    Zwitch.openSavingsAccount({
      containerId: 'savingContainer',
      credentials: credentials,
      callbacks: {
        onSuccess: (resp) => { console.log(resp); },
        onError:  (resp) => { console.log(resp); },
      }
    });
}
</script>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>

   ''');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put the complete error message into the question **body**, not in the question title.

Comment: To solve the storage problem by chance, [make sure the page is loaded before accessing the local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415248/1948292).

Comment: You can try moving the inline event handlers `onclick` into JavaScript event handlers like `document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {});`. Otherwise you'd probably need access the the embedded websites CSP headers and alter them in the response to include unsafe-inline event handlers.

Comment: This is the complete error message
 "Uncaught (in promise) SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.", source: https://elements.zwitch.io/zwitch-elements/dist/zwitch-elements/p-51a1781a.js (3)
E/FrameEvents(13977): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline HTML, put HTML code inside a HTML file and add in the asset folder. Then declare the asset in pubspec.yamel file and call inside WebViewPlus widget

```
WebViewPlus(
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: 'assets/payment.html',
            zoomEnabled: false,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              this.controller = controller;
            },
          ),
```